# Send an email alert when httpd goes down

Tags: apache-httpd

I want to be notified whenever httpd.service fails.

I see [ExecStopPost](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStopPost=), and I was wondering if there is a similar alternative for httpd.

Or would it be a better approach, to send an email notification when the server itself restarts?